# Does ActionBar Compatibility introduced in v 18 works without issues with android:configChanges="orientation" on pre ICS devices?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I incorporated ActionBarSherlock to application and than i found that it will probably never work (according to developer) with android:configChanges="orientation" and now behaves wrongly. So does new support library implementation of ActionBar works with android:configChanges="orientation" on pre ICS devices ?

Comment: Why not give it a try and share result here?

Comment: soon, but I will happily accept your answer also :)

Comment: Yes it will work! I've tested it in one of my apps with
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" on a few  devices <3.0. I've already released the app with these changes and got no negative user feedback.

Comment: If you want some reputation just answer this question and I will accept.